# How to set up form on website?

Tags: php, html, css, forms

So far I have the basic text input.

```
 <form name="contact" method="post" action="contact.php">
<div id="subscribe">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address...">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

This is my code for my "Coming Soon" landing page. What I wan't to figure out is how to have the emails entered send somewhere for me to access. I've tried adding PHP but I fail (I'm net to web development) .

This is the PHP code I'm trying to use

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
$email_subject = "Your email subject line";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if  !isset($_POST['email']) ||
   died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

  $error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
  }
   $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

 // create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
   ?>
   <?php
    }
     ?>
```

Anytime I try nothing happens. If you know a shorter way of doing this please let me know or another way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but you really new to learn the basics first, your code is full of possible errors. Download an IDE or a tool that helps you with syntax highlighting, and for the beginning, simply use ready-to-go forms from PHP tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What people are saying is:

```
//<form method="post"> 
// Why do you have two form starts? Get rid.


<form name="contact" method="post" action="contact.php"> 
    <div id="subscribe"> 
        // you have to give the INPUT a name attribute. 
        // If you want to access the data using $_POST['email'], 
        // then you have to name it 'email'
        <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address...">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
        <div class="clear"></div> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious problem is you have your entire script testing for a POST vairable that isn't in your form. Make this change to your HTMl and I bet it works.

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address...">
```

EDIT
To clarify this some, `$_POST` is an array filled with the form fields you submits. So `$_POST['email']` requires you to submit a form with a field named `email`. No field name, no easy way to reference it

Comment: This is the HTML so far 
     <form method="post">

 <form name="contact" method="post" action="contact.php">
<div id="subscribe">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address...">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</form>
But the email isn't sending. Is there any editing to do in the PHP?

Comment: @Colourity what Machavity is saying is you have to add the "name" attribute to your input before the server will "see" it. Forms pass name value pairs, that it gets from the various inputs in the form. If you don't name your input you don't have a name-value pair.